# service doesn't keep constant control of main thread on UI

Tags: android, user-interface, service

I have a service in my Android application that has a UI its running. The problem I am running into, it that on various devices, it doesn't seem to maintain control of the main thread. For instance, it does not ALWAYS respond to the back button being pressed. Is there a way to ensure that the service always has control of the UI?

Thanks.

Comment: Service should not control UI, at least not directly. Activity should be responsible for UI management.

Comment: I can't use an Activity...This is for an InputMethodService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! For anyone that cares, I need to called the startForeground method for the Service.